# Sending ints, receives wrong data

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to send the player's position (x, y) to the client from the Server. Everything else seems to work, but not these 2 ints. I can send other integers, for example 3456, and it will receive 3456. But these wont work.

Server Java code:

```
    public void sendAccountInformation() throws IOException {
            dos.write(player.id);
                main.log(player.id);
            dos.println(player.username);
                main.log(player.username);
            dos.write(player.x);
                main.log(player.x);
            dos.write(player.y);
                main.log(player.y);
            dos.write(player.mapid);
                main.log(player.mapid);

            dos.flush();
        }
```

Server output:

```
0
sdfsdffsd
544
384
0
```

The above is the correct information that should be sent.

Client Java code:

```
    public void loadAccount() throws IOException {
            int id = dis.read();
            main.player = new Player(id, main);
                main.log(id);

            main.player.username = dis.readLine();
                main.log(main.player.username);

            main.player.x = dis.read();
                main.log(main.player.x);
            main.player.y = dis.read();
                main.log(main.player.y);
            main.player.mapid = dis.read();
                main.log(main.player.mapid);
        }
```

Client output:

```
0
sdfsdffsd
63
63
0
```

As you can see, the two integers (544 and 384) was changed into (63 and 63). But EVERYTHING else sends and is received correctly?

Comment: Please post your relevant code here on this site.

Comment: Um? Instead of linking to a pastebin containing the URL of a screenshot, could you just paste the code into a code formatting block?

Comment: Can you show us a short very of the code which reproduces this problem? e.g. without GUI code which isn't needed.

Comment: well, did you mean that, you can send one int while you need to send two?

Comment: How are you sending the player's position to the client?

Comment: We would still benefit from your posting  more pertinent information. Such as what type is the "dos" variable? What about dis? You seem to be confusing numbers with unicode text representation. You need to parse those Strings to get numbers.

Comment: write() does not write ints. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should try using [writeInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29) and [readInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29) to write and read `int`.

Comment: I will try that and post the result. Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks everyone for your help. :) Someone tell me how to set this question to "SOLVED"